# Webpack: loading dependencies from local directory

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "my-module-1": "file:../modules/my-module-1",
    "my-module-2": "file:../modules/my-module-2",
    "my-module-3": "file:../modules/my-module-3"
  },
```

If I install dependencies, it is finished successfully. However, in map `node_modules`, `my-module-x` is a shortcut, which lead to the weird errors for babel-loader. If I copy-paste my modules into `node modules`, it is working very well. In previous versions of webpack,  they were always copied. Now using webpack 3.6.0.

So, my question is: is there another way of defining dependency in package.json, or a plugin that copies the modules (from package.json) from another directory to `node_modules` without creating a shortcut.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1643#issuecomment-352087287

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-module": "file:a_map/my-module", 
    // a_map folder is on the same level as this package.json file
}
```

Works very well with settings:

`Npm (6.12.0)` and

[image]

Comment: Using "file:" the local changes are ignored, so this is not helping for package development.